# Using a 12V lighted toggle switch with an Arduino

Tags: arduino

I would like to connect a 12V lighted toggle switch to an Arduino and be able to read its state (replacing the momentary button in [this tutorial](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Button) with [this switch](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2062493)).  But the Arduino has only 5V power supply.  Can I connect the 12V switch to the 5V power supply?

**Update:**

There are just three contacts on this particular switch. The contacts are labeled source, ACC (presumably accessory) and ground. When you close the switch, it connects source to ACC and also connects source through the lamp to ground. There is just a single power source in the circuit.

Comment: Can anyone supply a schematic for this? as there was not one posted, shouldn't giving a DC voltage ground blow components?

Answer (score 4):

I can't see anything about the lighting on the link you gave.

The lighting is normally separately controlled. You have 3 contacts for the switch (that's usually a change-over switch, though the description says SPST), and a couple of pins where you connect the lamp. Use a transistor to drive the lamp from your Arduino, then the Arduino's output pin won't see the 12V, and connect the switch like in the tutorial.

If the switch should happen to be connected directly to the lamp, so that it also switches 12V (it may explain that third pin), you'll have to use a resistor divider to bring the 12V from the switch down to the 5V the Arduino's input can digest. Never apply 12V directly to the input.

**edit** (after your edit)
If I understand correctly source and ground are your power supply. ACC (whatever it may mean) is the switched V+, which is also used to power the lamp. In that case you simply need a voltage divider between ACC and the Arduino input. The ratio should be 2:3, for instance a 30k\$\Omega\$ between ACC and the Arduino input, and a 20k\$\Omega\$ between the input and ground. That will divide the 12V from the switch by 20k\$\Omega\$/(20k\$\Omega\$+30k\$\Omega\$), so you get 4.8V out.

Comment: I added some more information about the switch.

Comment: I'd like to accept this (sorry that it's several months old now), but I don't understand what the resisters are for. There is only one power supply, which is the 5V power supply from the arduino. There shouldn't be 12V from the switch; where would it come from?  Close the switch and you get current flowing from the 5V source to ground *and* to ACC. I suspect that the lamp is actually an LED, so I'm guessing that there is a resister inside the toggle to bring the voltage down to something the LED can handle. If the resister is for 12V, that should mean dim or no light at 5V, right?

Answer (score 1):

I would draw a diagram for you, but I'm currently on a mobile device.

My suggestion would be to use a 5V relay. Connect the Arduino Digital pin to it and connect a 12V source upto the other part of the relay with the light attached. That way, when you send the Arduino high, the relay switches on and allows the 12V to flow through to the light.

You also wanted to read the output state on the light. You could always add a variable in so that whenever the relay pin changes from high/low, the variable can change from 1/0. If you want to physically read the state, you could hook back the 5V from the relay pin to one of the input pins, but to me, this seems unnecessary.

Hope this is helpful. I'll post a diagram ASAP.

Comment: "the relay switches on and allows the 12V to flow through to the light". 12V doesn't "flow", current flows. And the lamp is controlled by the switch, read OP's update of the question. You don't want a relay.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also interested in this solution too, but my assumption is 12V lighted toggle switch does not connect to 12v power supply. I use it with the Arduino UnoJoy flight simulator panel.

A 12v lighted toggle switch has 3 terminals/contacts (12v, GND, ACC)

An Arduino UNO use one digital pin, GND

According to my experiment , there have

1. if 12v connect to a digital pin, Acc of switch connect to GND of Arduino, you can off/on switch and receive a status in Arduino off/on (no LED light)
2. if 12v connect to a digital pin, GND of switch connect to GND of Arduino, you can off/on a switch and LED will off/on (no digital status)
3. if 12v connect to a digital pin, Acc of switch connect to GND of Arduino and GND of switch connect to GND of Arduino, you can off/on a switch and receive a status in Arduino without LED light.
4. if 12v connect to  GND of Arduino, Acc of switch connect to a digital pin and GND of switch connect to GND of Arduino,

4.1  Switch off stage will get LED on, digital pin off

4.2  Switch on stage will get LED off, digital pin on

5. From above result of item 4, together with minor edit a sketch , using digitalRead(pin-no) instead of !digitalRead(pin-no)

5.1 Switch off stage will get LED on, digital pin on

5.2 Switch on stage will get LED off, digital pin off

Now I will have a 12V lighted toggle switch work with Arduino UnoJoy for a flight simulator panel , just physically reverse a label plate off/on to on/off.